# SQL top [parameter]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I would like to do something like this:

```
declare @a int
set @a = 10

select top @a * from tbl
```

(Basically the @a is going to come from a system setting table)

Can I do this without dynamic sql string?

Comment: Yes but be aware that `TOP` without `ORDER BY` isn't deterministic; any arbitrary rows may be returned.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works (nearly) as provided. At least under SQL Server 2016 this is valid and returned a result:

```
DECLARE @a int
SET @a = 10

SELECT TOP (@a) [Per_ID]  
FROM [tbl_Personen]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select a.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seq
      from tbl t
     ) t
where seq <= @a;
```

However, if you do parenthesis `()` around `TOP` clause this will also work :

```
declare @a int
set @a = 10

select top (@a) t.* 
from tbl t;
```

**Note** : Without using `ORDER BY` clause this will be random rows return.